# Pattern Matching search under Snowflake array

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column, "ext", in table T1. It contains extensions for each participant with a delimiter #&#. E.g.

Table - T1

| id | name | ext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | <ext_1>=value>#&#<ext_2>=value>#&#<ext_3>=value> |
| 2 | Mike | <ext_1>=value>#&#<ext_2>=value>#&#<ext_4>=value> |
| 3 | Luke | <ext_1> = value |

I need to create a single column containing a JSON object that includes the required extension.

E.g. If I need ext_2 and ext_4. Then it should be like -

| id | name | ext | json_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | <ext_1>=<=value>#&#<ext_2>=value>#&#<ext_3>=value> | {<ext_2>:value>} |
| 2 | Mike | <ext_1>=value>#&#<ext_2>=value>#&#<ext_4>=value> | {<ext_2>:,<ext_4>:value>} |
| 3 | Luke | <ext_1>=value> | NULL |

This way I could search the table effectively.
I'm using Snowflake to achieve this.

My Approach:-

1. Create a UDF function that accepts the column.
2. Use ILIKE expression to find whether the required extension is available.
3. If yes, then split based on delimiter to receive an array
4. Figure out a way to extract ext_2=value & ext_4=value
5. Split them based on '=' to receive an array ['ext_2',value,'ext_4',value]
6. User object construct to create a JSON

I'm figuring out how to achieve step 4.

Feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear to me why you are not converting the whole column to JSON, just specific extensions. Doesn’t that mean that if you wanted to search for a different extension you would have to re-process the whole table again?

Comment: @NickW, I completely understand your concern. Let's say if we have to approach your way then how would you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values in the ext column into a valid JSON string and then write this out to the json_field column (which should be a VARIANT).

There are probably lots of ways of creating the JSON string but I did it with a number of nested REPLACE functions - just identifying the patterns in the source string and replacing them with the appropriate pattern (or removing them) for the json string. If you wanted this logical to be reusable then, however you write it, it would make sense to wrap it in a function:

```
update TEST1
set json_field = 
PARSE_JSON(
     REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
              REPLACE(to_variant(EXT)::variant,'>#&#<', '", ')
           ,'>=', ': "')
         ,'<=')
        ,'<','{') 
     ,'>', '"}')
)::VARIANT 
;
```

You can then query for any extension e.g. this queries for ext_1

```
SELECT 
  json_field,
  json_field:ext_1
  FROM TEST1;
```